# Response from WebSocket is not possible to be read (only partialy)

Tags: java, websocket

I have WebSocket client which is reading response from server into `InputStream`. I would like to get it into `String` to process it further (it is `xml` document) but I am not getting whole response.

Approach:

```
public String recv() throws java.io.IOException {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(mInput);
        StringBuffer inputLine = new StringBuffer();
        String tmp;
        while ((tmp = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            inputLine.append(tmp);
            System.out.println(tmp);
        }
        dis.close();
        return inputLine.toString();
    }
```

I get

> [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 48733;
> The element type "original_severity" must be terminated by the
> matching end-tag "</original_severity>".]

Because response is not complete and my XML pareser is not able to parse response

Comment: what websocket client are you using ? Did you create your own ?

Comment: I used my own ` SocketFactory factory = sslsocketfactory.getDefault(); factory.createSocket(mUrl.getHost(), mUrl.getPort())`

Answer (score -1):

A websocket message sent by a server may be split into several frames.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5

You have to make sure your client re-assemble the whole message before trying to parse it.

It will be far easier using a third party websocket client as those librairies usually hide this part of the protocol.